# Unable to disconnect/destroy/unpublish opentok stream

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, opentok

I'm building a basic audio/video chat feature and all seems to work fine but i'm not able to get rid of session and it doesn't get destroyed.

I have tried it just as in the docs:

```
call_session = OT.initSession(params['api_key'], params['session_id']);
```

I get `session_id` from server which is using PHP SDK.

Following are event `streamCreated` and `streamDestroyed`

```
call_session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {

call_stream = event.stream;

var subscriber = call_session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', {
   insertMode: 'append'
   }, CHAT_CALL.handleError);
});  

call_session.on("streamDestroyed", function(event) {
   console.log("Stream " + event.stream.name + " ended. " + event.reason);
});
```

And here is the session connect call:

```
call_session.connect(params['token'], function(error) {
                // If the connection is successful, publish to the session
                if (error) {
                    CHAT_CALL.handleError(error);
                } else {
                    // console.log("Connected !!!");
                    // Create a publisher
                    call_publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', {
                        insertMode: 'append',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        publishAudio: enable_audio,
                        publishVideo: enable_video,
                        // style: {
                        //     buttonDisplayMode: 'on'
                        // }
                    }, CHAT_CALL.handleError);
                    call_session.publish(call_publisher, CHAT_CALL.handleError);
                }
            });
        }
```

But the problematic part is the the below function where i try to unpublish and disconnect session.

```
end_call: function(){
  call_session.disconnect();
  call_session.unpublish(call_publisher);
  call_publisher.destroy();
}
```

Calling `end_call` gives me below error:

`The publisher XYZ is trying to unpublish from a session ABC it is not attached to (it is attached to no session)`

Followed by below error:

`Invalid state transition: Event 'disconnect' not possible in state 'disconnected'`